# What is the effect of magnetic field on PHASE of instrinsic spin of fermion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, quantum-spin

As part of my bucket list of things to understand before I die, I'm looking at and trying to understand variations of the Stern-Gerlach experiment. (I haven't studied physics since I was at school and I haven't studied any quantum mechanics since I was an undergraduate.) In a nutshell my question is;

**how does measuring the intrinsic spin of a non-relativistic fermion in a specific axis affect the phase of that spin?**

Here's an explanation of what is confusing me on this topic...

My understanding is that if I plan to apply a magnetic field to a non-relativistic fermion in an attempt to measure intrinsic spin I will be measuring that spin in one specific axis determined by the direction of the magnetic field. I intend to try all sorts of different axes not just 'x' and 'z', so I make use of all three Pauli matrices as a vector $\vec{\sigma}$, scaled using the components of a unit vector $\vec{a}$ that defines the axis I'm using like this:

$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{\sigma}=a_1\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}+a_2\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}+a_3\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_3&a_1-ia_2\\a_1+ia_2&-a_3\end{pmatrix}$$

I have formulae for finding the eigenvectors for the matrix above taken from wikipedia. Here is just the one for the negative eigenvector:

$$\psi_-=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2|\vec{a}|(a_3+|\vec{a}|)}}\begin{bmatrix}ia_2-a_1\\a_3+|\vec{a}|\end{bmatrix}$$

**However, if I happen to set my arbitrary axis to the x or y axis the negative eigenvector I get differs from eigenvector solutions quoted for those axes in the literature.**

E.g. for negative measurements on the positive y axis:

The literature says  $\psi_{y-}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\-i\end{pmatrix}$  but I get  $\psi_{y-}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} i\\1\end{pmatrix}$

It dawned on me that both solutions are correct eigenvectors for the axis of choice - the two solutions only differ in phase (in complex space). Correct?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Done. (I think - I deleted the follow up question anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It dawned on me that both solutions are correct eigenvectors for the axis of choice - the two solutions only differ in phase (in complex space). Correct?

Yes, that's right. The overall phase is irrelevant, so your $\psi_{y-}$ is just as good as the one you found in the literature.  Two vectors which differ by an overall phase represent precisely the same physical state, so you may use whichever one you'd like - nothing physically observable depends on this choice.

> When the measurement is made, will the phase be randomised or unchanged? How do we define 'unchanged' in terms of spinors? I'm thinking about an experiment in which relative phase is important - e.g. a two slit interference experiment with differently oriented magnetic fields behind the slits.

Let $A$ be an observable which has a (non-degenerate) eigenvalue $\lambda$, and let $|\phi\rangle$ be the corresponding normalized eigenvector (which is only well-defined up to a phase). If the initial state of the system is $|\psi\rangle$ and you measure $A$ to take the value $\lambda$, then the un-normalized post-measurement state will be given by $|\phi\rangle\langle \phi|\psi\rangle$ (which you may normalize, if you wish).

The projection operator $|\phi\rangle\langle \phi|$ is insensitive to the phase of the $|\phi\rangle$ that you choose. Furthermore, the relative phase between the initial state $|\psi\rangle$ and the final state $|\psi'\rangle = |\phi\rangle\langle \phi|\psi\rangle$ is
$$\Delta \theta \equiv \mathrm{arg}\big(\langle \psi'|\psi\rangle\big) = \mathrm{arg}\big(\langle\psi|\phi\rangle\langle \phi|\psi\rangle\big)$$
$$= \mathrm{arg}\big(|\langle\phi|\psi\rangle|^2\big) = 0$$
where $\mathrm{arg}$ is the [complex argument](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexArgument.html).  In this sense, the projective measurement does not change the phase - but remember, there is really no meaningful way to define the phase of a given vector, so what we're really saying is that the *relative* phase of the pre-measurement state vector and the post-measurement state vector is zero.

Comment: When the measurement is made, will the phase be randomised or unchanged? How do we define 'unchanged' in terms of spinors? I'm thinking about an experiment in which relative phase is important - e.g. a two slit interference experiment with differently oriented magnetic fields behind the slits.

Comment: FYI, I've created a GeoGebra resource so I can play with the maths. [link](https://www.geogebra.org/m/tcre7tnz)

Comment: Oops, meant to reference your handle @j-murray in the comments above.

Comment: @jon_m I've added a few comments to my answer.

Comment: @j-murray Thanks, that really pins it down in a way that makes sense even with my limited familiarity with the subject.

Comment: @jon_m Glad to hear it! As a small extension, if the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is degenerate (meaning that there are multiple eigenvectors $|\phi_i\rangle$ with the same eigenvalue), then the projection operator (which was $|\phi\rangle\langle \phi|$ in my answer) becomes $\sum_i |\phi_i\rangle\langle \phi_i|$ (where we take the $|\phi_i\rangle$'s to be orthonormal). The rest of the answer proceeds exactly as before, and once again the relative phase between the pre- and post-measurement states is zero.